# How to run multiple Discord clients simultaneously

Tags: python, discord.py, python-asyncio

I've created a few bots using the discord.py library and I now want to build a 'dispatcher' that reads a configuration file and launches them all. Each of my bots is created as a class extending from an abstract bot class. However, I'm stuck at running them simultaneously. These are some things I've tried:

- Using threads. Eg: `threading.Thread(target=discord.Client('token').run)).start()`. Doesn't work because `Client.run()` tries to start the `asyncio` event loop again, causing an error (`RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop`).
- Using `os.system`/`multiprocessing`/`subprocess`. To run `.py` files containing bots. Doesn't work because `os.system` etc blocks until the subprocess has ended (ie the bot is killed). I'd also prefer not to use this method because it's a bi
- Creating tasks and putting them on a single `asyncio` loop (shown below).

MRE of the last method I tried:

```py
import discord
import asyncio

class Bot:
    client = discord.Client()

    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token

        print('Bot initiated')

        @self.client.event
        async def on_ready():
            print(f'Logged in as {self.client.user}')
        
        @self.client.event
        async def on_message(message):
            print(message.content)
        
    async def run(self):
        print('Bot running')
        self.client.run(self.token)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot1 = Bot('bot token here')
    bot2 = Bot('bot token here')
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.create_task(bot1.run())
    loop.create_task(bot2.run())
    loop.run_forever()
```

This doesn't work at all - the first bot freezes in the `run` method and never even logs in. For testing, both bots were logging into the same bot account but that's irrelevant to the problem.

I presume that the ideal solution would be a way to asynchronously run a `discord.Client`, but I haven't come across any way to do this.

Comment: It seems like what you want it to, just each bot from the command line and sent it to the background. This you do not have to do from within python. An example would be `python my_daemon.py &`

Comment: @JakobGuldbergAaes I can run them all manually but I want to create a python script to run them automatically.

Comment: just use subprocess.Popen then. Which is literally callen the shell from within python. Same same but a tad different, but it gets the jobs done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest approach would be using [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

```py
import sys
import subprocess

files = ["bot1.py", "bot2.py", ...]

for f in files:
    subprocess.Popen(
         [sys.executable, f], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE
    )
```

It will start all the files in the background.

Comment: Thanks! It's probably not the cleanest way of doing it but it works.

Comment: It's probably not, if you're familiar with [`Docker`](https://docker.com), you might wanna use [docker compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/)

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer in the github of discord.py [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/516)

```
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.create_task(bot1.start(your_args))
loop.create_task(bot2.start(more_args))
loop.run_forever()
```

so instead of using the bot.run() method which blocks the entire thread, you call the bot.start method and block it yourself using run_forever().